# tinymce remove other options for table plugin except the grid

Tags: javascript, tinymce

[image]

Is it possible to remove the other options except the table grid for tinymce 4 table plugin? Id like to add the quicktable toolbar like the one in tinymce inlite theme

I have the following code currently

```
  tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea.documentWysiwyg',
        plugins: "nonbreaking table",
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | outdent indent | table',
        table_toolbar: "",
        nonbreaking_force_tab: true
    });
```

Comment: see documentation: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/table/

Comment: @bananaCute Did you ever find a solution for this? I too am looking for a way to only have the grid option show up for the table plugin when using the inline editor for tinymce.

Comment: have you found a solution? I would also prefer to have a quick toolbar action to insert a table using grid, without other features.

Comment: We are also still looking for a solution. Any news on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We found a workaround for this issue!

You can create a new custom MenuButton (but it can be added to the toolbar!), which uses the `inserttable` (so called grid).

```js
private readonly setupCallback: (editor: Editor) => void = (editor: Editor) => {
    //...
    editor.ui.registry.addMenuButton('customInsertTable', {
      icon: 'table',
      fetch: (callback) => {
        const items: any[] = [
          'inserttable'
        ];
        callback(items);
      }
    });
  };
```

Add the new attribute (`customInsertTable`) to the toolbar.

You should end up with ->

[image: Result]

Answer (score -2):

Yes! It is  possible.

Have you practiced your Google-foo lately? I Google'd `tinymce table plugin`, opened the first link and there it is, as the first option - `toolbar`.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/table/#table_toolbar

## table_toolbar

> This option allows you to specify the buttons and the order that they
>   will appear on within TinyMCE's inline contextual toolbar for tables.
>   To specify the controls that should appear on TinyMCE's table toolbar,
>   the `table_toolbar` option should be provided with a space separated
>   list of toolbar controls. To create groups within this list, please
>   add `|` pipe characters between the groups of controls that you would
>   like to create. If you want to disable this toolbar simply set the
>   value to an empty string.

Example given:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",  // change this value according to your HTML
  table_toolbar: "tableprops tabledelete | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol"
});
```

Comment: I already tried setting the option to empty string, it still shows all options in the table dropdown.

Comment: @bananaCute If you have already tried a solution then it should be included in your answer. The options should be disabled but not really removed in a UI sense.